# Bootstrap 4 - Remove active class on nav-link

Tags: jquery, css, html, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a Bootstrap 4 `navbar` with the `nav-item` that have the active class. My problem is when I use the `active` class I can't remove it from the `nav-item`

How can I remove the active class on the `nav-item`?

This my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
       <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
               <small>LOGO BRAND</small>
            </a>
             <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-
             label="Toggle navigation">
                 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
             </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown menu-large">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">   
               Dropdown Menu</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-custom megamenu megamenu-custom">
                <div class="row">
                  <li class="col-md-3">
                    <ul>
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Glyphicons</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Available glyphs</a></li>
                      <li class="disabled"><a href="#">How to use</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdowns</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Aligninment options</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Headers</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Disabled menu items</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-md-3">
                    <ul>
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Button groups</li>
                      <li><a href="https://www.google.it" target="_blank">Basic example</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Button toolbar</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Sizing</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Nesting</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Vertical variation</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Button dropdowns</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Single button dropdowns</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-md-3">
                    <ul>
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Input groups</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Basic example</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Sizing</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Checkboxes and radio addons</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Navs</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Tabs</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Pills</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Justified</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-md-3">
                    <ul>
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Navbar</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Default navbar</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Buttons</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Text</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Non-nav links</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Component alignment</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Fixed to top</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Fixed to bottom</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Static top</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Inverted navbar</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.menu-large {position: static !important;}

.megamenu {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}


.megamenu > div > li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.megamenu > div > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}

.megamenu > div > li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: normal;
}

.megamenu > div > li > ul > li > a:hover,
.megamenu > div > li > ul > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  background: none;
  /*background-color: #f5f5f5;*/
}

.megamenu .dropdown-header {
  color: #428bca;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link{
  color:red!important;
}
```

This is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.navbar-nav .nav-item').click(function(e) {
       $('.navbar-nav .nav-item').removeClass('active');
       var $this = $(this);
       if(!$this.hasClass('active')){
           $this.addClass('active');
       }
       e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

JSFiddle Link where you can see the example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/so8e5pug/224/)

Can you help me to resolve the problem?.

Comment: When do you want to remove the class?

Comment: I want remove the active class when I click on it

Comment: Sorry @lealceldeiro for disturb. Can you explain me why when I remove the active class from a nav-link via JQuery I have active this particullarly CSS Code:                                                                                                     
 .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}

Comment: Because that rule is activated by the hover event. In order to override it you must declare the same rule in your custom css file and set the color you want the links to have (check this plunker: https://jsfiddle.net/lealceldeiro/ga75c3eq/9/) and see how the colors don't change when the mouse goes over the links (`hover`)

Comment: there is a way to highlight the nav-link ( so your eyes focus on the element ), and when you click on it to unhighlight, the CSS class.nav-link:focus, .nav-.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus,.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover { color: rgba(0,0,0,.7) ; } it's hidden?  See this example http://jsfiddle.net/A6dqQ/7/