# Remove active class on nav-item

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

When I remove the `.active` class on bootstrap 4 nav-item, why does the following CSS rule remain active?

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link, 
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, 
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, 
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
```

Here's my example:

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var isActive = $this.hasClass('active');
  $("a").removeClass("active");
  isActive ? $this.removeClass("active") : $this.addClass("active");
});
```

```css
nav a {
  display: block;
}

nav a.active {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a href="#">FooBar</a>
  <a href="#">FooBar</a>
  <a href="#">FooBar</a>
</nav>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A6dqQ/7/)

Comment: Depending on the browser, when you inspect an element and look at the css rules affecting it, the one that is affecting it amongst many will be bolded slightly.

Comment: Add a working snippet for us so we can help out.

Comment: I post here the JSFiddle link with use of active class on Bootstrap 4: https://jsfiddle.net/developer2018/n21s6c97/15/, and the link where you find the example of my question: http://jsfiddle.net/A6dqQ/7/. Thank you for help me guys

Comment: @showdev this solution it's very good but the problem is here:  isActive ? $this.removeClass("active") : $this.addClass("active"); ,  because this class ( .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
} ) with Chrome Debugger remains active like during the debugging and after.

Comment: That's not my solution; it's the code from your JSFiddle. Can you help to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: this is the JSFiddle link updated: http://jsfiddle.net/developer2018/n21s6c97/22/ and this link is that I would like be: http://jsfiddle.net/A6dqQ/7/. Thank you for your support. I'm searching a solution from 1 week

Comment: Didn't you already ask this same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52545159/bootstrap-4-remove-active-class-on-nav-link

Comment: you are reason @zim. I "duplicate" the question because anyone answered me. I'm so sorry